# Android App Keeps Crashing

Tags: android

I keep on getting an error when ever i open my android application

> The application app_name(process com.random.stuff) has stopped unexpectedly. 
>      Please try again

Logcat

```
04-04 05:51:39.975: D/AndroidRuntime(480): Shutting down VM
04-04 05:51:39.975: W/dalvikvm(480): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.joseph/com.random.stuff.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.random.stuff.StartingPoint.(StartingPoint.java:17)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
04-04 05:51:40.076: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  ... 11 more
```

StartingPoint:

```
    package com.thenewboston.joseph;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

    Button bGuess;
    TextView points, hint, result;
    EditText guess;
    String dog = "Dog";
    String guessDog = guess.toString();
    int point = 0;

    boolean isDog = ((String) hintp).contains("Has four legs and fur");
    boolean isFrog = ((String) hintp).contains("Has four legs and is slimy");
    boolean wrong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

        bGuess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGuess);
        points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tPoints);
        hint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHint);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tResult);
        guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGuess);

        bGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                hint.setText("Has four legs and fur");
                if (isDog) {

                    if ("dog".equals(guess.getText().toString())) {
                        wrong = false;
                        hint.setText("Has four legs and is slimy");
                    }
                } else {
                    wrong = true;
                }

                if (isFrog) {
                    if ("frog".equals(guess.getText().toString())) {
                        wrong = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    wrong = true;
                }

                if (wrong) {
                    point--;
                    result.setText("False try again");
                    points.setText("Points: " + point);
                }else{
                    point++;
                    result.setText("Correct");
                    points.setText("Points: " + point);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

DDMS Line:

```
04-04 08:30:28.194: I/DEBUG(31): debuggerd: Feb  3 2011 14:45:34
04-04 08:30:28.225: D/qemud(38): entering main loop
04-04 08:30:28.244: I/Vold(29): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
04-04 08:30:28.264: I/Netd(30): Netd 1.0 starting
04-04 08:30:28.274: D/Vold(29): USB mass storage support is not enabled in the kernel
04-04 08:30:28.274: D/Vold(29): usb_configuration switch is not enabled in the kernel
04-04 08:30:28.274: D/Vold(29): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
04-04 08:30:28.504: D/Vold(29): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
04-04 08:30:28.565: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 9
04-04 08:30:28.565: D/qemud(38): created client 0xe078 listening on fd 10
04-04 08:30:28.565: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'boot-properties'
04-04 08:30:28.565: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 1
04-04 08:30:28.574: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 1
04-04 08:30:28.574: I/qemu-props(52): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
04-04 08:30:28.574: I/qemu-props(52): receiving..
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=32m
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): receiving..
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): receiving..
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): receiving..
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=none
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): receiving..
04-04 08:30:28.584: I/qemu-props(52): exiting (4 properties set).
04-04 08:30:28.584: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 10
04-04 08:30:29.084: D/AndroidRuntime(33): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
04-04 08:30:29.084: D/AndroidRuntime(33): CheckJNI is ON
04-04 08:30:29.314: I/(34): ServiceManager: 0xad50


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/bGuess"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:text="Guess" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tPoints"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bGuess"
     android:text="Points: " />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tHint"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:text="Result: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tHint"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Hint: \n"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/eGuess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bGuess"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bGuess"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bGuess"
    android:ems="10" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please provide some code of your activity.

Comment: Please upload the code of your activity as well

Comment: You have `NullPointerException` at `StartingPoint.java:17`, something is assigned there to `NULL`. Check it out.

Comment: The error is at line number 17 in your Java code, at com.random.stuff.StartingPoint. Null pointer exceptions can be a result of referencing wrong xml components too. Post your code for better answers.

Comment: sorry i was getting a error when trying to add the starting point code it is there now

Answer (score 2):

You are facing `NullPointerExcetion` because of this line `String guessDog = guess.toString();`

just replace it with `String guessDog;`

Now get text on onClick() method as follows,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
guessDog = guess.getText().toString();  // Add this line
.
.
```

Here is the updated code from my side, I have done few changes init

- I removed @dimon values from .xml as it was not with me ( you can keep it in your code )
- I removed hintp this line instead i gave direct value as `true`

Here is my code,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class StartingPoint extends Activity 
{

    Button bGuess;
    TextView points, hint, result;
    EditText guess;
    String dog = "Dog";
    String guessDog;
    int point = 0;

    boolean isDog = true;
    boolean isFrog = true;
    boolean wrong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

        bGuess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGuess);
        points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tPoints);
        hint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHint);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tResult);
        guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGuess);

        bGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                guessDog = guess.toString();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                hint.setText("Has four legs and fur");
                if (isDog) {

                    if ("dog".equals(guess.getText().toString())) {
                        wrong = false;
                        hint.setText("Has four legs and is slimy");
                    }
                } else {
                    wrong = true;
                }

                if (isFrog) {
                    if ("frog".equals(guess.getText().toString())) {
                        wrong = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    wrong = true;
                }

                if (wrong) {
                    point--;
                    result.setText("False try again");
                    points.setText("Points: " + point);
                }else{
                    point++;
                    result.setText("Correct");
                    points.setText("Points: " + point);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: oh windows 7 and the computer i built

Comment: ok though so also i did it just then and what application do i have to install

Comment: do i have to setup something in eclipse or do i just press run as android application

Comment: ok, do this setting on your device, Go to Settings-> Application-> tick the "Unknown Sources" and then there is another option called "Development" select it and tick "USB debugging". After this again run your application.

Comment: how do you get to settings

Comment: Click on menu, and you will see other application. setting is also there, with a `gear` kind of image.

Comment: is menu a button on the toolbar because i cant find it